# OCaml literal negative number?

Tags: syntax, ocaml

I'm learning. This is something I found strange:

```
let test_treeways x = match x with
  | _ when x < 0 -> -1
  | _ when x > 0 -> 1
  | _ -> 0;;
```

If I then call it like this:

```
test_threeways -10;;
```

I will get type mismatch error (because, as far as I understand, it interprets unary minus as if it was partial function application, so it considers the type of the expression to be `int -> int`. However, this:

```
test_threeways (-10);;
```

acts as expected (though this actually calculates the value, as I could understand, it doesn't pass a constant "minus ten" to the function.

So, how do you write constant negative numbers in OCaml?

Comment: Style comment: pattern matching is best at destructuring values. This exercise should rather be an if construct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to enclose it in order to avoid parsing amiguity. "test_threeways -10" could also mean: substract 10 from test_threeways.

And there is no function application involved. Just redefine the unary minus, to see the difference:

```
#let (~-) = (+) 2 ;; (* See documentation of pervarsives *)
val ( ~- ) : int -> int = <fun>
# let t = -2 ;; 
val t : int = -2 (* no function application, constant negative number *)
# -t ;;
- : int = 0   (* function application *)
```

Comment: Only if without the space the source would be lexed in a different way. Whitespace is just to delimit tokens. If you don't put whitespace between two alphanumeric identifiers they form a single bigger one etc.

Comment: So is it a precedence thing or a parsing thing? I don't fully understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [~-](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Pervasives.html#6_Integerarithmetic) and ~-. directly (as hinted in the other answer), they are both explicitly [prefix operators](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml-4.00/lex.html#prefix-symbol) so parsing them is not ambiguous.
However I prefer using parentheses.