# Why this recursion example in ocaml doesn't work for negative number?

Tags: recursion, ocaml

In the Think [Ocaml book](http://greenteapress.com/thinkocaml/thinkocaml.pdf) the author gave this example:

```
let rec countdown n = 
    if n <= 0 then 
      ( print_string "Blastoff!"; 
        print_newline()) 
    else ( print_int n; print_newline(); 
       countdown (n-1); ());;
```

The function takes an int and returns a unit. However, the code suppose to work on negative numbers as mentioned in the book but it doesn't.
The logic of the code seems fine and nothing wrong with it. I thought I would share it with people who know Ocaml to see what is wrong here.

Comment: What happens when you pass in a negative number? Can you show us the code you ran and what the output was?

Comment: Error: This expression has type int -> unit
       but an expression was expected of type int

Comment: How do you write it? It seems to me you write `countdown -1` in which case it is seen as `countdown` to which you substract 1, write `countdown (-1)` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OCaml literal negative number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16041393/ocaml-literal-negative-number)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing

```
countdown -1
```

doesn't mean what you expect it to mean. The problem is that - is an infix operator with the following signature:

```
# (-);;
- : int -> int -> int = <fun>
```

As you can see it is a function taking 2 integer arguments and returning an integer. It's the subtraction "a - b".  The above statement will be parsed as:

```
(countdown) - (1)
```

And countdown has type `int -> unit` instead of the expected type `int`.

What you want instead is the unary minus that negates a number. The ocaml grammar is written so that an expression starting with - uses the unary minus but any minus in the middle of an expression is the binary minus. So you have to write one of the following:

```
countdown (-1)
countdown ~-1
```

Answer (score 0):

Presented as an alternative leveraging the [`Seq`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Seq.html) module, we can deconstruct this problem into a few different parts:

- A sequence of numbers counting down from a starting point.
- Cut off that sequence at `1`.
- Print each number in turn on its own line, then print `"Blastoff!"`

Because sequences are lazy, we don't need to worry about when to stop when creating the function which generates the sequence. We can just use `Seq.take_while` to control that.

```
# let rec countdown ~from () =
    Seq.Cons (from, countdown ~from:(from - 1))
  in
  countdown ~from: 10
  |> Seq.take_while (fun n -> n > 0)
  |> Seq.iter (Format.printf "%d\n%!");
  print_endline "Blastoff!";;
10
9
8
7
6
5
4
3
2
1
Blastoff!
- : unit = ()
```